# how to add .csr certificate in wso2 enterprise integrator 7 ide in xml

Tags: wso2-esb

hi can anyone tell me how to add the .csr certificate from the curl command to wso2 enterprise integrator in xml.
curl -v -X POST --cert {{path_to_client_certificate_generated_in_developer_portal} } --cert-type DER --key {{insert_path_to_private_key_used_to_create_CSR}} -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "x-fapi-financial-id: test" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=accounts&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjhkZThjYTc3LWQ2ODEtNDc4Mi04MTIyLWUwMzkyNTg5MDIxYiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIyMTFlMzZkZS02NGIyLTQ3OWUtYWUyOC04YTViNDFhMWE5NDAiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3NhbmRib3guaHNiYy5jb20vcHNkMi9vYmllL3YzLjEvYXMvdG9rZW4ub2F1dGgyIiwic3ViIjoiMjExZTM2ZGUtNjRiMi00NzllLWFlMjgtOGE1YjQxYTFhOTQwIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk5MTgzNjAxLCJleHAiOjE3NzkzNDg1MjF9.uu282OmEHUa0t6z6T68MfXzEGGgq8PiWuyJxuNQ1be6iWdD5sVbw3W--_O6TFAH-ae7BYXsE0kncYgA6gF9AmkXuA77w_Wbn2YyjPCB9gDCkrlJUS6rvb3UJYcIBZ7W-WZlRAsRE0l6EV74c5xnyL9c7cpGMfQ-HfPsYOG4JCsrvtpAHdo7jHWTVgKoe67jWGQkNOYt1Ba7rCf4y-fqQ3d6hZoptAAcJd26yigvV4768GHQGrBvgAc7OzutOGzYARAgStpjQMp0kMiOGIzq-TUsDlvtMrx2fH8gfy2uG2HvzsROkbNedL-iO5PmswNrDvCYEWZmVjMcaVg--ZF0sjg' "https://sandbox.hsbc.com/psd2/obie/v3.1/as/token.oauth2"

```
<resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/getAccounts">

    <inSequence>

        <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>

        <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>

        <header name="x-fapi-financial-id" scope="transport" value="test"/>

        <header name="Cache-Control" scope="transport" value="no-cache"/>

        <property expression="$trp:grant_type" name="client_credentials" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

        <property expression="$trp:scope" name="accounts" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

        <property expression="$trp:client_assertion_type" name="urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

       <!--   <property expression="json-eval($.authorization)" name="prop.bearer.token" scope="default" type="STRING"/> -->

        <payloadFactory media-type="json">

            <format>{
```

"grant_type": "$1",

"scope": "$2",

"client_assertion_type": "$3"

}

```
            <args>

                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:grant_type"/>

                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:scope"/>

                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:client_assertion_type"/>

            </args>

        </payloadFactory>

        <call>

            <endpoint>

                <http method="post" statistics="enable" uri-template="https://sandbox.hsbc.com/psd2/obie/v3.1/as/token.oauth2">

                    <suspendOnFailure>

                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>

                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>

                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>

                    </suspendOnFailure>

                    <markForSuspension>

                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>

                    </markForSuspension>

                </http>

            </endpoint>

        </call>

        <sequence key="conf:sequence/HttpFaultSequence.xml"/>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your requirement? Do you want to add the certificate to the wso2 client trustore or do you want to send the certificate to a different system through ESB?

Comment: i need to  add the certificate .der and  RSA private key  from my local system  to esb integration studio.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your requirement is to update the Keystore in the micro integrator packed with the Integration studio. You can update the Keystore directly from the Integration studio installation location. In mac this location is

```
/Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/repository/resources/security
```